# TSQL: Check if distributor exists before executing sp_dropdistributor

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to check if the distributor exists before dropping it using this command in T-SQL?

```
exec sp_dropdistributor @no_checks = 1, @ignore_distributor=1
```

Something like this:

```
If (Distributor Exists) Then 
   exec sp_dropdistributor @no_checks = 1, @ignore_distributor=1
```

I'm trying to avoid this error that gets generated when I execute that statement and the distributor does not exist:

> Msg 21043, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_dropdistributor, Line 50
>   The Distributor is not installed.

Comment: [sp_helpdistributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helpdistributor-transact-sql) perhaps

Comment: You can query using a select.  Normally I execute an Update query and check the return value for rows modified.  If no row are modified then the primary key doesn't exist so I then execute Insert query to add new item.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-get-distributor-transact-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `sp_get_distributor` procedure:

```
    declare @temp table
    (
        is_installed int,
        distribution_server_name varchar(500),
        is_distribution_db_installed int,
        is_distribution_publisher int,
        has_remote_distribution_publisher int
    );

    insert @temp exec sp_get_distributor

    if((select is_installed from @temp) = 1)
    begin
      exec sp_dropdistributor @no_checks = 1, @ignore_distributor=1
    end
```